# Laravel 8 - Insert using multiple join and calculation laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, laravel-8

I want to solve the following problem using one query for example

**Questions Table**

```
 id  |  question | correct_answer | point

 1   | "what ..?"| 'test'         | 10
 2   | "what ..?"| 'test'         | 5
```

**Answers Table**

```
id |  question_id | user_id | answers | point
```

Using **Laravel 8** I want to add answers to multiple questions at the same time using join and get scores from the questions table and if user answers match to questions.correct_answer also add its score to answers table
use something like code:

```
DB::table('questions')->join('answers','answers.question_id','=','questions.id')
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: why not achieve this by using Database View.

Comment: how i can achieve this using database view?

Comment: Wait, should the answers table contain the row with the highest point value or did you really mean to leave it empty?

Comment: i want for example if user answers question one then it will find answers in questions table and if it is right then add number in answer points table from questions points table